# Tail a file while it's open for writing

Tags: files, tail

I'm writing continuously to a file, and I want to tail it from another shell. But it seems that as long as the file is open for writing,

```
tail -f filename
```

can't show all the new lines until the file is closed again.

Unfortunately, opening and closing the file many times a second slows my script down to the point where data is received faster than it can be written, so I can't close the file during the process.

The writing is being done by a python program:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM2',9600)
f   = open("filename", "a+")
while True:
    s    = ser.readline()
    f.write(s + "\r\n")
```

Isn't there a way to view the contents of a file that is in the process of being written to?

Comment: Do you mean `tail -f <file>`? Or better: `tail -F <file>`, the uppercase F will follow even if the file does not exist yet or is logrotated etc.

Comment: This is either a matter of not using `tail -f` on the file, or of the program writing to the file doing buffering (either explicitly or, more likely, implicitly).  How are you writing to the file?  Buffering of output is done for performance reasons, but the data would not be written until the buffer is full.  Sometimes buffering can be avoided.

Comment: Seconding the thought that this is most likely a buffering issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't see it with `tail`, it's not in the file.

It might be in the write buffer of the Python program, though. The customary behavior when writing to files is that the C library buffers outputs until a full block is written (e.g. 4096 bytes or such) instead of sending all the writes to the OS immediately. This saves on system call overhead. This is similar in Python. <sub>(I'm not sure if it uses the C library, or if it does similar buffering itself, but the end result is the same.)</sub>

For output to the terminal, the default is line buffering: the buffer is written out when a newline is written. Of course, any buffers are also flushed if the file is closed, but that's indeed not very efficient.

To fix that, either call `f.flush()` after each `f.write()`, use disable the buffering altogether. There are some ways to do that in this question on SO: [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering)

Comment: Sorry it took so long. f.flush() indeed did the trick; I just didn't discover it until now, because I was accessing the text file over SSHFS which apparently buffers a lot. So now I have a new problem - or rather the same problem, but now I need a new solution :-) Thanks!